Relationship between eigenvalues of transition matrix and singular values of generator
Say I have a Markov Chain with transition matrix $P$ and define its generator as $L=I-P$. What can I say about the relationship between the eigenvalues of $P$ and the singular values of $L$? I know that when $P$ is normal I can express one as the other but this is to broad of a restriction. Ideally, I would like to bound the eigenvalues absolutely by some expression of their equivalent singular values. Any help or relevant references would be much appreciated.
